# Is there any possibility for creating task scheduler on monthly based in python?

Tags: python, windows, automation, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to create monthly task schedule based on user input like, StartBoundary datetime, selected months, DaysOfWeek, WeeksOfMonth however i am getting error,

I can create daily task trigger successfully. however this monthly task scheduling didn't working.

```
    trigger.DaysOfWeek = [2, 3, 4] # Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday

    File "C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Internal\Task Scheduler\task\Lib\site- 
    packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 686, in __setattr__
    self._oleobj_.Invoke(entry.dispid, 0, invoke_type, 0, value)
    pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352571, 'Type mismatch.', None, 1)
```

1. Here is my script:

   ```
    import win32com.client
    import datetime as dt
    set_time=dt.datetime(2022,10,6,2,5,58,500000)

    computer_name = "" #leave all blank for current computer, current user
    computer_username = ""
    computer_userdomain = ""
    computer_password = ""
    action_id = "Test Task" #arbitrary action ID
    action_path = r'C:\Users\Somesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 
    #executable path (could be python.exe)
    action_arguments = r'windows_patching.py' #arguments (could be something.py)
    action_workdir = r"D:\Practice\patch1.0" #working directory for action executable
    author = "Somesh" #so that end users know who you are
    description = "testing task" #so that end users can identify the task
    task_id = "Test Task"
    task_hidden = False #set this to True to hide the task in the interface
    username = "myuser"
    password = "mypassword"



    #define constants
    TASK_TRIGGER_DAILY = 2
    TASK_TRIGGER_MONTHLY = 3
    TASK_CREATE = 2
    TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE = 6
    TASK_ACTION_EXEC = 0


    #connect to the scheduler (Vista/Server 2008 and above only)
    scheduler = win32com.client.Dispatch("Schedule.Service")
    scheduler.Connect(computer_name or None, computer_username or None, computer_userdomain or 
    None, computer_password or None)
    rootFolder = scheduler.GetFolder("\\")

    #(re)define the task
    taskDef = scheduler.NewTask(0)
    colTriggers = taskDef.Triggers
    trigger = colTriggers.Create(TASK_TRIGGER_MONTHLY)
    trigger.StartBoundary = set_time.isoformat()
    trigger.Enabled = True

    trigger.DaysOfWeek = [2, 3, 4] # Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday
    trigger.WeeksOfMonth = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    trigger.Months = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

    colActions = taskDef.Actions
    action = colActions.Create(TASK_ACTION_EXEC)
    action.ID = action_id
    action.Path = action_path
    action.WorkingDirectory = action_workdir
    action.Arguments = action_arguments

    info = taskDef.RegistrationInfo
    info.Author = author
    info.Description = description

    settings = taskDef.Settings
    settings.ExecutionTimeLimit = "PT2H"
    settings.RestartInterval = "PT1M"
    settings.RestartCount = 3
    settings.Enabled = True
    settings.Hidden = task_hidden
    logon_type = 1
    #register the task (create or update, just keep the task name the same)
    result = rootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(task_id, taskDef, 
    TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE,username, password, logon_type)
   ```

could you please let me know which part i have mmised. that would be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: (1) Some constants used seem to have wrong value. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/taskschd/ne-taskschd-task_trigger_type2 (2) Some properties you want to use aren't available for `MonthlyTrigger` but only for `MonthlyDOWTrigger`. (3) These properties are bitsets.

Comment: Hello @MichaelButscher, thanks for the reference link.  I will review it. 